# Simple debug results in internal server error

Tags: views, 8, hooks, debugging

All I want to do is print a view out so I can check the variables and see the structure of what's being created but it results in an internal server error.

I'm using Acquia Dev Desktop. I've checked the .htaccess file and it has the rewritebase uncommented. I've tried updating max_execution_time, and memory_limit. Nothing helps.

I have Drupal 8 installed fine and haven't had any issues except when trying to inspect variables.

BTW here is my function in theme file:

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  print_r($view);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get ? How many views do you display on the desired page ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hi!!** you can use a official symfony dumper, insert this line on the file "composer.json"

```
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/var-dumper":"3.0.4"
  }
```

run the follow command:

```
composer install "symfony/var-dumper"
```

or

```
composer update
```

you can use in your code with these line:

```
dump($variable_name);
```

enjoy!!! ;)